# javascript increment setInteval counter while video is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, timer, settimeout

I have the following code that detect if user is idle or not. On page load, a timer will run and if the user is idle for a certain of seconds the timer will pause and resume if the user is active. And I have also codes that detect if video is playing, if the video is playing timer should run and if the video is stop/pause a timeout will run and detect if the user is still active

The problem is even if video is playing, the timer paused and it will start to idle. What I want is when video is playing timer should countinue to increment.

Heres my code:

```
function setPlayingVideoToTrue(){playing_video = true;}

function setPlayingVideoToFalse(){playing_video = false;}

// check if a video iframe exists
var iframe_videos = $('body').find('iframe');

if(iframe_videos.length > 0){
// create ready events for every iframe
iframe_videos.each(function(index){
    // add a temporary id for the iframe
    // append additional parameters to the end of the iframe's src
    var temporary_player_id = 'iframe_player_'+ index;
    var new_iframe_src = $(this).attr('src') +'?api=1&player_id='+ temporary_player_id;
    $(this).attr('id', temporary_player_id);
    $(this).attr('src', new_iframe_src);

    // add event listener for ready
    $f(this).addEvent('ready', iframe_ready);
});

// when a player is ready, add event listeners for play, pause, finish, and playProgress
function iframe_ready(player_id) {
    $f(player_id).addEvent('play', setPlayingVideoToTrue);
    $f(player_id).addEvent('playProgress', setPlayingVideoToTrue);
    $f(player_id).addEvent('pause', setPlayingVideoToFalse);
    $f(player_id).addEvent('finish', setPlayingVideoToFalse);
}
}


function start_idle_timer(){
var timer = 0;

function increment_duration()
{   
    if(isPaused === false)
    {
        timer++;
    }

    // increment timer if video is playing
    if(playing_video === true){
        clearTimeout(idleTimer);
        isPaused = false;
    }


    if(playing_video === false && isPaused === false){

        // stop timer if the user is idle for 3 minutes
        var idleTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            // console.log('idle');
            clearInterval(check_time);
            isPaused = true;

            // a modal will apper to inform that user is on idle state
            $('#linkage').trigger('click');

            var modal_timer = 0;
            // timer for modal idle timer
            continue_modal_timer = setInterval(function(){
                modal_timer++;

                inactivity_timer = modal_timer;
                if(modal_timer == 60)
                {
                    clearInterval(continue_modal_timer);
                    clearTimeout(idleTimer);    
                }
            }, 1000)    
        }, 10000);
    }

    // bind to all elements on DOM possible events indicating the user is active
    $('*').bind('mousemove click mouseup mousedown keydown keypress keyup submit change mouseenter scroll resize dblclick', function () {
        clearTimeout(idleTimer);
        isPaused = false;
    });
}

// initialize the interval
check_time = setInterval(increment_duration, 1000); 
}

// check if start_timer is present from the loading page to record the time duration of the user
if($('.start_timer').length > 0){   
start_idle_timer();
}
```